# Sequelize duplicate foreign key

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

It is mentioned [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#customizing-the-foreign-key) that there is no need to specify the foreign key twice in an association, like the example below:

```
const Image = sequelize.define('Image', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  url: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  tableName: 'Image'
});

Image.belongsTo(Product, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'productId',
    allowNull: false
  }
});

Product.hasMany(Image);
```

But if I do like it is said it is producing two foreign keys in the table one named `productId` which is the one I mention in the association, and another created by Sequelize named ProductId.

The only way I found is to do this instead

```
Image.belongsTo(Product, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'productId',
    allowNull: false
  }
});

Product.hasMany(Image, {
  foreignKey: 'productId'
});
```

Does anyone knows what is happening, did I missed something ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned piece of the official documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#customizing-the-foreign-key) just shows two different approaches: implicit and explicit next to each other

```js
// Option 1:
// shows using an explicit foreign key name as a string
Foo.hasOne(Bar, {
  foreignKey: 'myFooId'
});
// shows using an implicit foreign key name which will be fooId (a model name + Id)
Bar.belongsTo(Foo);

// Option 2
// shows using an explicit foreign key name as an object
Foo.hasOne(Bar, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'myFooId'
  }
});
// shows using an implicit foreign key name which will be fooId (a model name + Id)
Bar.belongsTo(Foo);

// Option 3
// shows using an implicit foreign key name which will be fooId (a model name + Id)
Foo.hasOne(Bar);
// shows using an explicit foreign key name as a string
Bar.belongsTo(Foo, {
  foreignKey: 'myFooId'
});

// Option 4
// shows using an implicit foreign key name which will be fooId (a model name + Id)
Foo.hasOne(Bar);
// shows using an explicit foreign key name as an object
Bar.belongsTo(Foo, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'myFooId'
  }
});
```

I agree that these examples look confusing so I'd show the difference in this way:
**Explicit** foreign key:

```js
// IMPORTANT: usually the same foreign key value should be indicated in both associations that describes relationship between two models in both directions.
// Explicit foreign key as a string
Foo.hasOne(Bar, {
  foreignKey: 'myFooId'
});
Bar.belongsTo(Foo, {
  foreignKey: 'myFooId'
});
// Explicit foreign key as an object
Foo.hasOne(Bar, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'myFooId'
  }
});
Bar.belongsTo(Foo, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'myFooId'
  }
});
```

**Implicit** foreign key:

```js
// uses fooId as a foreignKey (a model name + Id)
Foo.hasOne(Bar);
Bar.belongsTo(Foo);
```

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly, indeed it is confusing.