# Sequelize - Relationships between tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

So, I have two data tables for a MariaDB database, named `User` and `Token`. There is a relation between the two: a user can have multiple tokens, while a token can only have one user (one to many). Using Sequelize I have made the following two models:

user.js (for `User` table):

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('user', {
        uuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        lastTokenRequest: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    })

    return User;
}
```

token.js (for `Token` table):

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Token = sequelize.define('token', {
        uuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        token: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        requestedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        expiresAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    })

    return Token;
}
```

To connect the two, I have made a file named associations (as I have seen more here on StackOverflow), which looks like this:

associations.js:

```
const { User, Token } = require('./index');

User.hasMany(Token);
Token.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'userId'
})
```

Whenever I try and run the code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasMany')
    at Object.<anonymous> (project_path\models\associations.js:3:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at project_path\models\index.js:30:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project_path\models\index.js:29:4)
```

Does someone know what might be wrong with this code? I use the latest release of Sequelize 6.

I tried executing this code, and changing the imports within associations.js. I also tried adding the relations within the table files, within the module.exports.

Comment: What does the index.js file look like?

Comment: The way you've set up that code, you're exporting functions that have to be *called* in order for the `sequelize.define()` calls to happen. I don't see those calls in what you posted.

Comment: And use the same options for both assocations either with explicit `foreignKey` option or with implicit foreign key. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76854570/1376618